# Combining multiple layers in PNG image with standalone PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm using a standalone pyqgis script on Ubuntu 16.04 and QGIS 2.18 to print custom maps as PNG files. The script is loosely based on [this script](https://github.com/rjspiers/qgis-standalone-map-export).

My goal is simple: print multiple layers in a single PNG file, but I'm encountering some issues.

The script below adds up to three layers (`layer_dev`, `layer_parks`, `layer_blgs`) using `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer_name)`.

If I include just the two first layers (and comment out `layer_blgs`), the PNG correctly contains both layers. If I include all three layers, then only the third is displayed in the PNG, and the two first are not printed.

At first I thought there was possibly some white background or something in `layer_blgs` masking the 2 first layers, but this behavior is similar regardless of the order with which I add the `layer_blgs`.

I also replicated manually the exact configuration (layers and corresponding style files) in QGIS to see if I was missing something, but the displayed map was, as expected, a combination of all layers.

I didn't find anything in the [documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html) that explains this issue, but suspect it might have to do with either the `QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge()`, or with the final composition rendering `composition.renderPage(imagePainter, 0)`.

Is there an explicit way to force all three layers to be printed in the final PNG?

```
root_path = '/home/me/sw/qgis'
result_path = '../../media/maps/tmp'
schema_name = 'webservice'
project_name = str(sys.argv[1]) #e.g. '048'
iteration_nb = str(sys.argv[2]) #e.g. '001'
alternative_nb = str(sys.argv[3]) #e.g. '633'
sol_nb = '001'

# Set output DPI
dpi = 300


def make_pdf(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, filter_expression):
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    # Set canvas extent
    canvas.setExtent(QgsRectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))

    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
        # set host name, port, database name, username and password
    uri.setConnection("host_name", "port", "myDB", "myUsername", "pwd")


    # DEV BORDERS
    # Set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionally subset (WHERE clause)
    uri.setDataSource("mySchema", "myTable", "geom")
    print "loading boundary development layer"
    lyr_dev = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "boundary development", "postgres")
    if not lyr_dev.isValid():
        print "Layer 'boundary development' failed to load! Probably not existent."
    else:
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr_dev)
        lyr_dev.loadNamedStyle(root_path + '/layerStyles/dev' + '.qml')
        lyr_dev.triggerRepaint()

    # PARKS
    # Set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionally subset (WHERE clause)
    uri.setDataSource(schema_name, "p" + project_name  + "_" + iteration_nb + "_" + alternative_nb + "_" + sol_nb + "_blg", "geom", "building_type = 'park'")
    print "p" + project_name  + "_" + iteration_nb + "_" + alternative_nb + "_001_blg"
    print "loading parks layer"
    lyr_parks = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "parks", "postgres")
    if not lyr_parks.isValid():
        print "Layer 'parks' failed to load! Probably not existent."
    else:
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr_parks)
        lyr_parks.loadNamedStyle(root_path + '/layerStyles/parks' + '.qml')
        lyr_parks.triggerRepaint()

    # BUILDINGS
    # Set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionally subset (WHERE clause)
    uri.setDataSource(schema_name, "p" + project_name  + "_" + iteration_nb + "_" + alternative_nb + "_" + sol_nb + "_blg", "geom", "building_type <> 'park'")
    print "p" + project_name  + "_" + iteration_nb + "_" + alternative_nb + "_001_blg"
    print "loading buildings layer"
    lyr_blgs = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "buildings", "postgres")
    if not lyr_blgs.isValid():
        print "Layer 'buildibgns' failed to load!"
    else:
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr_blgs)
        lyr_blgs.loadNamedStyle(root_path + '/layerStyles/2.5d-height_label-floorstotal' + '.qml')        
        lyr_blgs.triggerRepaint()


#bridge used in standalone script: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadproject.html; has to be created before further layers are loaded
    bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot(), canvas)
    bridge.setCanvasLayers()



    # Load print composer template
#     template_path = root_path + sty['qpt'] + '.qpt'
    template_path = root_path + "/printComposers/autoexport" + '.qpt'
    template_file = file(template_path)
    template_content = template_file.read()
    template_file.close()

    document = QDomDocument()
    document.setContent(template_content)
    composition = QgsComposition(canvas.mapSettings())
    composition.loadFromTemplate(document, {})
    composition.refreshItems()

    # export to png
    dpmm = dpi / 25.4
    width = int(dpmm * composition.paperWidth())
    height = int(dpmm * composition.paperHeight())

    # create output image and initialize it
    image = QImage(QSize(width, height), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    image.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmm * 1000)
    image.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmm * 1000)
    image.fill(0)

    # render the composition
    imagePainter = QPainter(image)
    composition.renderPage(imagePainter, 0)
    imagePainter.end()


    image.save(result_path + '/' + 'STH' + "_" + project_name + "_" + alternative_nb + "_" + sol_nb + '.png', "png")

    QgsProject.instance().clear()

make_pdf(2495987, 1113541, 2497513, 1114926, '') # this requires: (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, filter_expression), set filter_expression = '' if not needed
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```